# Assume a photon has a wave function, what can be said about its Hamiltonian and eigenvalues?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, photons

I understand a photon does not have an associated wave function, but what if we assumed a photon does in fact have a wave function. How would this look and how could its Hamiltonian be determined?

Comment: Have a look at this article that describes the quantum mechanical wavefunction of the photon https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0604169 . btw, eigen values do not describe a particle but a bound solution of a quantum mechanical problem. Photons are not bound, they are the increment in energy between energy levels in qunatum  mechanical potential problems  with charged particles.

Comment: in the answer to this question, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/718510/on-the-eigenvalues-of-parity-operator  operators can  have eigenvalues too, but the photon is an elementary  particle

Answer (score 1):

In classical mechanics, a particle with 0 mass is not so clear, and this extends to quantum mechanics as well.

In relativity, however, light has a rigorous framework. In relativity, $E \neq \frac{p^2}{2m}$ for a free particle. It's instead:

$$E^2 = (mc^2)^2+(pc)^2$$

and so for light, which has 0 mass:

$$E^2=(pc)^2 \implies E=pc$$

So in some sense, you can define the photon hamiltonian (in 1 dimensional case) as:

$$H = c i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$

So The Schrodinger Equation becomes:

$$i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} =i \hbar c \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x} \implies \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = c \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}$$

---

Note that for a complete hamiltonian of a photon, you actually need to learn about relativistic quantum mechanics. This is because even though for a photon:
$$E=pc$$

momentum is still a 3-vector while energy is a number. And the Schrodinger equation would have a gradient which is a vector.

To fix this, you need to work with relativistic equations which keeps energy squared and momentum squared:

$$-\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2 \psi^\mu}{\partial t^2}=-\hbar^2 c^2\nabla^2\psi^\mu \implies \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 \psi^\mu}{\partial t^2}=\nabla^2 \psi^\mu$$

Which you can say is Maxwell's equation describing light. But this also doesn't give the complete picture. Because I'm trying to keep the answer in the scope of your question, I cannot answer. For a complete picture, you need QFT. For more information check [this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_wave_equations)